# On the irrationality of Euler Mascheroni constant

Tags: irrational-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

I saw one of the expansions of Euler Mascheroni constant in terms of Meissel Mertens constant as a consequence of Mertens theorem.

$$ B = \gamma + \sum_p \left\{ \log\left( 1 - \frac 1p\right) + \frac 1p\right\}$$

This is that expansion. Now I don't understand why is it difficult to prove the irrationality of Euler Mascheroni constant. Since we have infinitely many prime numbers, the sum over all those primes in the above equation, if converges must be a irrational, then why is it not considered as a proof of irrationality?

Comment: For $any$ $x\in\Bbb R$ let $r_1$ be irrational with $r_1<x.$ For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $r_{n+1}$ be irrational with $x-(x-\sum_n)/2<r_{n+1}<x,$ where $\sum_n=\sum_{j=1}^nr_j.$ Then $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}r_n=x.$

Comment: Can you give the reference where you have seen this formula ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the derivation of that constant is available in Hardy & Wright's _An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers_.

Comment: @TravorLZH Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

“if converges must be a irrational” is asserting what you need to prove. There’s no obvious reason for such a series to converge to an irrational number, and for all we know it may not.

Furthermore, even if this infinite sum is irrational, that doesn’t establish that $\gamma$ is irrational, since not much is known about the Meissel-Mertens constant you denoted by $B$.

Comment: I made a comment to the Q to show that any $x\in \Bbb R$ is the sum of an infinite sequence of irrational reals.

Comment: Every real number, rational or irrational, is actually the sum of just two irrational numbers. Irrational x = x/3 + 2x/3, rational x = pi + (x - pi).

Comment: I copied that equation from Wolfram alpha and also saw it in Wikipedia. And none of comments actually is talking about my question. The infinitude of primes imply that that summation actually is irrational. And coming to its convergence, I am thinking that we can first take summation by parts and introduce the prime counting function and retain the sum over primes by converting to sum over all natural numbers and use Cauchy convergence test.

Comment: “The infinitude of primes imply that that summation actually is irrational” – no, it doesn’t, and I can’t imagine why you would think that. An infinite sum over primes can be perfectly rational.